# Is there a way to identify in onStartCommand of a service if it's created by system for STICKY?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a foreground service running and it is a STICKY_REDELIVER_INTENT service. The problem is that every time it starts again due to sticky service behaviour, notification will be displayed with sound. This happens many times in a day and it will be definitely irritating to the user. Is there a way to restrict notification sound only to the first time it's displayed?

Comment: use a shared pref for that, for the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this service is running or not. if not running then you can start service.

For check service is running or not:

```
if (isMyServiceRunning(MainActivity.this, xyzService.class)) { // Service class name
    // Service running
} else {
    // Service Stop
}



public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Activity activity, Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```